# Wildfly 9 Session invalidation issue flushOnSessionInvalidation

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly-9

I am using Wildfly 9.0.2, And I configured jboss-web.xml as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<jboss-web>
    <security-domain flushOnSessionInvalidation="true">web_client_security</security-domain>  
    <context-root>cpro</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

On user logout action wrote following code.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
session.invalidate();
```

I also implemented the HttpSessionListener and checked whether session.invalidate() called the sessionDestroyed() method or not but this also called.

Now when user try to login again wildfly JAAS security does not call the login module

I used security domain in standalon-full.xml as follow

```
<security-domain name="web_client_security" cache-type="default">
...
</security-domain>
```

Does any one know how to solve this cache issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi did you ever manage to get this working? We are experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I don´t know the answer but there´s a [bug on Wildfly](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-5546) affecting version 10.0.0 RC3. Check the *is blocked by* and *is related to* issues as well. I couldn´t confirm that it also affects your version. I hope this helps you figuring out a solution. Good luck.